# how to add time with Time.now in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In controller:

`@delivery_time=(Time.now + @hotel.deliverytime.to_i).strftime("%I:%M")`

where `deliverytime=00:30:00`

I am getting a wrong answer of `@delivery_time`.I am getting `2014-12-12 05:50:00` after adding `Time.now=2014-12-12 17:20:00` and `deliverytime=00:30:00`.The answer should be `2014-12-12 17:50:00`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66756/discussion-on-question-by-uday-kumar-das-how-to-add-time-with-time-now-in-rails).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like that:--

```
duration = @hotel.deliverytime.hour * 60 * 60 + @hotel.deliverytime.min * 60 + @hotel.deliverytime.sec
@delivery_time=(Time.now + duration).strftime("%I:%M")
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails allows you to add a specific amount of days, hours, minutes,etc

```
Time.now+30.minutes
```

You can also do

```
Time.now+1.hour
Time.now+1.day
```

If your time is in a 00:00:00 string you can do something like

```
@delivery_time=(Time.now + (@hotel.deliverytime.split(':')[0].to_i*3600 + @hotel.deliverytime.split(':')[1].to_i*60 + @hotel.deliverytime.split(':')[2].to_i).seconds ).strftime("%I:%M")
```